# Zend Framework 2: subqueries

Tags: php, zend-framework2

ZF2 recently updated to version 2.1.4 with a database API has changed http://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2013-03

Now the code that I used for a subquery was an exception:

```
$sub = new Select('md_type');
$sub->columns(array(new Expression('COUNT(mt2.parent_id) as total')))
    ->where(array(
        new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('mt2.parent_id = mt1.id')
    ))
;

$subquery = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("({$sub->getSqlString()})");

$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select('mt1');
$select->columns(array('*', 'cnt' => $subquery));
```

> $sub->getSqlString() ------> Notice: Attempting to quote a value in Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql without extension/driver support can introduce security vulnerabilities in a production environment.

I can not find an alternative way to use subqueries. Please tell me how to be, how to use subqueries now. Thanks!

---

It's bug: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/4068

In the near future, I think it fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Please try this.

```
$sql = new Sql($this->_adapter);
$mainSelect = $sql->select()->from('mt1');
$subQry = $sql->select()
        ->from('md_type')
        ->columns(array('orderCount' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(md_type.parent_id)')))
        ->where('mt2.parent_id = mt1.id');
$mainSelect->columns(
        array(
            'id', 
            'total' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('?', array($subQry)),
        )
);

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($mainSelect);
$comments = $statement->execute();
$resultSet = new ResultSet();
$resultSet->initialize($comments);

return $resultSet->toArray();
```

Reference: [ZF2 - subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742290/subquery-in-zend-framework2/15743270#15743270)

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue trying to run subqueries with exists. I wrote up a blogpost with code examples that walk you through how to set it up. http://aronkerr.blogspot.com/2013/08/zf2-sql-exists-sub-query-using-zf2.html?m=1