# zf2 - subquery issue in model

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

i am getting sql syntax problem in zf2 subquery i dont knonw whats wrong with my query. my query is perfectly working on mysql

in zend it shows syntax error

**sqlQuery**

```
SELECT ( SELECT role_name FROM roles WHERE role_id=(SELECT role_id FROM users WHERE id=a.user_id)) AS role,`a`.consultant_id,`a`.*, `c`.`name` AS `name`, `b`.`name` AS `branchname`, `u`.`name` AS `consultantname`, `u`.`role_id` AS `role_id`, `r`.`role_name` AS `rolename` 
            FROM `agents` AS `a` 
            LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `c` ON `c`.`code` = `a`.`country` 
            LEFT JOIN `branches` AS `b` ON `b`.`id` = `a`.`branch_id` 
            INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `u`.`id` = `a`.`consultant_id` 
            INNER JOIN `roles` AS `r` ON `r`.`role_id` = `u`.`role_id` 
  WHERE  r.`role_id` IN(5,12,21,25,43,44) AND a.branch_id=63 AND a.consultant_id =2834 
  ORDER BY `a`.`id` ASC
```

**Zend Query**

```
        $rolesSelect = new Select();
        $rolesSelect->from(array('r1' => 'roles'));
        $rolesSelect->columns(array('ro_name'=>'role_name'));
        $rolesSelect->join(array('u1' =>'users'), 'u1.role_id = r1.role_id', array(''));
        $rolesSelect->join(array('a1' =>'agents'), 'u1.id = a1.user_id', array(''));

        $select = new Select();
        $select->from(array('a' => 'agents'));
        $select->columns(array('*','role_name1' => new Expression('?', array($rolesSelect))));
        $select->where($conditions);
        $select->join(array('c' =>'countries'), 'c.code = a.country', array('name'),'left');
        $select->join(array('b' =>'branches'), 'b.id = a.branch_id', array('branchname'=>'name'),'left');
        $select->join(array('u' =>'users'), 'u.id = a.consultant_id', array('consultantname'=>'name','role_id'=>'role_id'));
        $select->join(array('r' =>'roles'), 'r.role_id = u.role_id', array(''));
        $select->order('a.id ASC');
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        echo $conditions."<pre>";
        print_r($resultSet);
        die;
        return $resultSet->buffer();
```

Comment: Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `` FROM `agents` AS `a` LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `c` ON `c`.`code` = `a`.`cou' at line 1)

Comment: i am sure about my mysqlquery it is working fine but in zend i am not able to fit

Comment: yes i am writing in model file

Comment: You should write `new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression` instead of `new Expression` in query.

Comment: Also you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476109/zend-framework-2-subqueries

Comment: i have applied all the internet options but still not resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use zend expression instead see below example**

```
$select = new Select();
            $select->from(array('a' => 'agents'));
            $select->columns(array('*','consultantname' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('(SELECT u.name FROM users u WHERE u.id = a.consultant_id)')));
            $select->where($conditions);
            $select->join(array('u' =>'users'), 'u.id = a.user_id', array());
            $select->join(array('c' =>'countries'), 'c.code = a.country', array('name'),'left');
            $select->join(array('b' =>'branches'), 'b.id = a.branch_id', array('branchname'=>'name'),'left');
            $select->join(array('r' =>'roles'), 'r.role_id = u.role_ref_id', array('role_name'));
            $select->order('a.id ASC');
            $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($resultSet);die;
            return $resultSet->buffer();
```